# How to restrict Ionic 2 application installation if device is rooted or jail broken?

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic2

I have an **Ionic 2** and **Angular 2** application.
And I need to check if the device is rooted (Android case) or jailbroken (Ios case)?

I have tried the following packages (cordova plugins):

- `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-iroot --save`
  **IRoot**.isRooted(successCallback, failureCallback);
- `cordova-plugin-root-detection --save`
  **rootdetection**.isDeviceRooted(successCallback, errorCallback);

Unfortunately, none of them worked for me... both the plugins have similar implementation

I am not able to import neither **IRoot** nor **rootdetection**  classes from the `npm modules`.

If there is any way to restrict the app installation, please share your response.

Thanks in advance.
Piyush

Comment: could you share come code, because these plugins working fine for me. I want to see your code

Answer (score 3):

Refer this working code:

**RootDetection: Android only**

install plugin 
          ***cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-root-detection***

then write these code in **app.component.ts**

```
      declare var rootdetection:any;

      platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (typeof(rootdetection) !== 'undefined' && rootdetection) {
                rootdetection.isDeviceRooted((data) => {
                    if (data && data == 1) {
                        console.log("This is routed device");

                    } else {
                        console.log("This is not routed device");
                    }
                }, (data) => {
                    console.log("routed device detection failed case", data);
                });
            }
        });
```

**iRoot Plugin: Android & iOS**

install plugin 
          ***cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-iroot***

then write these code in **app.component.ts**

```
  declare var IRoot:any;

  if (typeof (IRoot) !== 'undefined' && IRoot) {
            IRoot.isRooted((data) => {
                if (data && data == 1) {
                    console.log("This is routed device");
                } else {
                    console.log("This is not routed device");
                }
            }, (data) => {
                    console.log("routed device detection failed case", data);
                });
        }
```

Comment: What do we import in app.component.ts here ?  Because the rootdetection comes as undefined.

Comment: That's common main page which executes on launch of the application

Comment: First of all.. thanks.. Here when I am debugging with a device. I see the rootdetection variable is undefined.

Comment: how you installed the plugin? i hope you accessing inside platform ready and in device build. if nothing helps this is may be the installation problem. remove and reinstall the plugin

Comment: and make sure that you have declared the plugin at top of the component page declare var rootdetection:any;

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked.. Just one question . Is this plugin works for ios as well ?

Comment: @PiyushGorey Root detection plugin supports only Android. If you need Ios support also then you can use IRoot plugin check the updated answer. iRoot supports android and ios even thought choose the plugin based on your requirement

Comment: This is working fine when the first time launch app, after that remove the app from a session, then launch the app, it says 'Root is not defined'.please any solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098970/iroot-is-not-defined-2nd-time-launch-the-app - any solutions?

Comment: Whats the best practice thing to do if you do detect that the device has been rooted?

Comment: @AnthonyJoanes Routed device having ultimate authority to do what ever the user wish to do in his device , network flow and even your app. Its not safer one to run your application in routed device. Check routed device on launch of application and check before every request to server. in case found clear all local data and freeze the app

Comment: Always getting undefined for IRoot and rootdetection. Tried this in both ngOnInit and ionViewDidEnter in app.component.ts file and also in main page ts file. But still getting undefined. Do we need add any provider in app.module.ts and in constructor? Can anyone pl. help me? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Solved this. "declare var IRoot:any;" has to be declared in global scope just after the imports.

Answer (score 2):

Related to **IRoot Plugin**, It can check if the device is rooted (Android case) or jailbroken (Ios case).

Steps:

1. import `cordova-plugin-iroot` package using the command
   `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-iroot --save`
2. declare IRoot as a var in the top of your class file
   `declare var IRoot: any;`
3. make sure to use the core code of the checking when the device is ready
4. returned data result expected to be boolean NOT number
   so you need to check against 'true' NOT '1'

Final script

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    IRoot.isRooted(
        (data) => {
          console.log('rooted device detection success case ' +  data);

          // check data value against true NOT 1
          if (data && data === true) {
            console.log('This is rooted device');
            // ... do anything when device is rooted

          } else {
            console.log('This is not rooted device');

          }
        },
        (data) => {
          console.log('rooted device detection failed case ' +  data);

        }
  );
});
```