# iRoot is not defined, 2nd time launch the app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

When the app is launched the first-time, this is working, after that remove the app from a session, then launch the app, it says

> IRoot is not defined

```
declare var IRoot: any;

ngOnInit() {
 this._platform.ready().then(() => {
   if (typeof (IRoot) !== 'undefined' && IRoot) {
       IRoot.isRooted((data) => {
           if (data && data == 1) {
              this.isRootedORJailBreak = true
              console.log("*******This is routed device");
         } else {
             this.isRootedORJailBreak = false
            console.log("*******This is not routed device");
        }
    }, (data) => {
            this.isRootedORJailBreak = false
           console.log("*******routed device detection failed case", data);
    });
    });
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the plugin isn't ready when cordova is ready, or isn't doing the registration at time.

You can try to wrap up your code inside of the `plataform.ready()` with a `setTimeout(() => { // your code }, 500);` and see if that works.

I saw your issue in github and the response that they gave you, but is just the same that you have tried here.

**UPDATE**

Move the code inside of the `this._platform.ready().then(() => {})` block to the `ionViewDidEnter` hook, the problem with the `ngOnInit` is that it can be cached and only will be called one time, the `ionViewDidEnter` will be called always, no matters if the component has been initialized before.

It seems that the problem was an issue with the cache.

Comment: Actually I am calling this in `ngOnInit` in the `app.component.ts`. Even though I called from `platform.ready()`, the second time I am getting the same error message. but the first time it is working? how?

Comment: Try with another hook, like `ionViewDidEnter` instead of `ngOnInit`, I want to check if this is a problem with the cache. Or check if the ``ngOnInit` is getting called the second time that you run the app, add a `console.log("foo")` inside of the `ngOnInit` block and another one inside of the `platform.ready().then(() => {/* here */})` block.This is just to check if the code was reached or not in the second startup.

Comment: I removed `this._platform.ready().then(() => {}` and  move code from `app.component.ts` to main login screen `ionViewDidEnter` method. It is working

Comment: Awesome, I will update the answer with the information posted here in the comments.

Comment: If you feel that this answer has resolved your question please set this answer as the solution, thank you.

Comment: Always getting undefined for IRoot and rootdetection. Tried this in both ngOnInit and ionViewDidEnter in app.component.ts file and also in main page ts file. But still getting undefined. Do we need add any provider in app.module.ts and in constructor? Can anyone pl. help me? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Raja45 did you add the IRoot js reference to the project? Check this comment from the owner of the repo: https://github.com/WuglyakBolgoink/cordova-plugin-iroot/issues/1#issuecomment-369512201

Comment: @dlcardozo Thank you so much. Solved this. "declare var IRoot:any;" has to be declared in global scope just after the imports.

Comment: @Raja45 that is awesome, happy coding!

Answer (score -3):

Remove the parenthesis around `(IRoute)` as it will first evaluate parenthesis content before `typeof (IRoute)`.

Having said that, IRout will still be undefined and you will need to take action when it's not defined.

if it's a remote library, trigger a onload event so that where it's needed can wait for it to load.

Comment: my requirement is if the device is rooted/jailbreak not allow further options. if IRoot is not defined, how can I check device rooted/jailbreak.? What is the action can be taken?

Comment: that's a different question I suggest you to create a new thread.